# Wikidata entity value from name

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

Is there a way to get Wikidata page information based on the name of the entity for example if I wanted to get page data for Google.
I think it has to be done using "entity" with the corresponding entity value however I am not sure of there is any easy way to determine the entity value.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to do this using the API, you would first use [`wbsearchentities`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbsearchentities) to find out which entity do you want. For example:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=Google&language=en

The problem with this is that there are multiple entities called "Google": the company (Google Inc.), the search engine (Google Web Search), the verb (to google) and even a Wikipedia disambiguation page.

After you somehow decide which entity to access, use [`wbgetentities`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities) to actually get the information you want:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q95&languages=en

Or, if you can't decide which entity to use, you could get information for all of them at the same time:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q95|Q9366|Q961680|Q1156923&languages=en

Comment: Hi @svick thanks very much! If you could provide one last bit of assistance - I'm having difficulties parsing the data in order to return say an array or a string of the entity numbers. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 11):

If you are familiar with Python you could do it programmatically with the Wikidata api, using [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) The following python script, obtains the wikidata entities. If you want the data objects for each individual wikidata entity, you need to uncomment the last two lines

```
 from pywikibot.data import api
 import pywikibot
 import pprint

 def getItems(site, itemtitle):
     params = { 'action' :'wbsearchentities' , 'format' : 'json' , 'language' : 'en', 'type' : 'item', 'search': itemtitle}
     request = api.Request(site=site,**params)
     return request.submit()

 def getItem(site, wdItem, token):
    request = api.Request(site=site,
                          action='wbgetentities',
                          format='json',
                          ids=wdItem)    
    return request.submit()

def prettyPrint(variable):
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(variable)

# Login to wikidata
site = pywikibot.Site("wikidata", "wikidata")
repo = site.data_repository()
token = repo.token(pywikibot.Page(repo, 'Main Page'), 'edit')
wikidataEntries = getItems(site, "Google")
# Print the different Wikidata entries to the screen
prettyPrint(wikidataEntries)

# Print each wikidata entry as an object
#for wdEntry in wikidataEntries["search"]:
#   prettyPrint(getItem(site, wdEntry["id"], token))
```

which results in

```
{   u'search': [   {   u'aliases': [u'Google Inc.'],
                       u'description': u'American multinational Internet and technology corporation',
                       u'id': u'Q95',
                       u'label': u'Google',
                       u'url': u'//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q95'},
                   {   u'aliases': [u'Google Search', u'Google Web Search'],
                       u'description': u'Internet search engine developed by Google, Inc.',
                       u'id': u'Q9366',
                       u'label': u'Google',
                       u'url': u'//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q9366'},
                   {   u'description': u'Wikipedia disambiguation page',
                       u'id': u'Q961680',
                       u'label': u'Google',
                       u'url': u'//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q961680'},
                   {   u'aliases': [u'Google'],
                       u'description': u'verb',
                       u'id': u'Q1156923',
                       u'label': u'google',
                       u'url': u'//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1156923'},
                   {   u'id': u'Q10846831',
                       u'label': u'google',
                       u'url': u'//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10846831'},
                   {   u'aliases': [u'Google Android'],
                       u'description': u'operating system for mobile devices created by Google',
                       u'id': u'Q94',
                       u'label': u'Android',
                       u'url': u'//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q94'},
                   {   u'description': u'web browser developed by Google',
                       u'id': u'Q777',
                       u'label': u'Google Chrome',
                       u'url': u'//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q777'}],
    u'searchinfo': {   u'search': u'Google'},
    u'success': 1}
```

Comment: i tried this but I keep getting the error `CRITICAL: Waiting for 1 network thread(s) to finish. Press ctrl-c to abort`, do you know what that is about? maybe I can somehow specify on what port to run it or soemthing?

Comment: You leave out `token = repo.token(pywikibot.Page(repo, 'Main Page'), 'edit’)` and the positional `token` argument in `def getItem(site, wdItem, token)` because you’re not editing anything at this point (sorry, I can’t edit the answer yet, my reputation isn’t sufficient).

Comment: Pay attention that by default the number of results are 7. If you want to get more results (limited to 50 for a user account), you need to add a `limit` parameter, for example : `params = {'action': 'wbsearchentities', 'format': 'json', 'language': 'en', 'type': 'item', 'search': search_string, 'limit': 50}` in `getItems()`

Comment: MAKE SURE to follow Kaleidophon's advice, delete line 24

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use sparql, to run a query:

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  ?item rdfs:label "Google"@en
}
```

You can use in python using pywikibot:

```
 import pywikibot
 from pywikibot import pagegenerators, WikidataBot

 sparql = "SELECT ?item WHERE { ?item rdfs:label 'Google'@en }"
 entities = pagegenerators.WikidataSPARQLPageGenerator(sparql, site=repo)
 entities = list(entities)
```