# 'from X import a' works but 'import X; X.a' doesn't

Tags: python, python-import

While integrating [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37201630/2186074) into a script, I wanted to change from :

```
import pywikibot
from pywikibot import pagegenerators

site = pywikibot.Site("wikidata", "wikidata")
repo = site.data_repository()

sparql = "SELECT ?item WHERE { ?item rdfs:label 'Google'@en }"
entities = pagegenerators.WikidataSPARQLPageGenerator(sparql, site=repo)
```

to:

```
import pywikibot

site = pywikibot.Site("wikidata", "wikidata")
repo = site.data_repository()

sparql = "SELECT ?item WHERE { ?item rdfs:label 'Google'@en }"
entities = pywikibot.pagegenerators.WikidataSPARQLPageGenerator(sparql, site=repo)
```

(i.e trying to merge the imports into a single one) but it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pywikibot' has no attribute 'pagegenerators'
```

(The same error on my desktop and on a Jupyter notebook in the cloud)

What am I missing ?

Comment: pretty-much-duplicate: [Why does this AttributeError in python occur?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8696322)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks, I guessed it has been already asked but was not able to find it.

Comment: **pagegenerators** is indeed a submodule, but that isn't the whole story. It is up to the pywikibot module's **__init__.py** file to decide what gets imported directly into your default namespace.   Many top level modules will import their submodules into the global namespace by doing **import <submodule** for you in their **__init.py__** file.  This is probably why you expect this behavior.  It is not uncommon for this to work because the module has in effect done the second import for you.  In this case, however, pywikibot's **__init__.py** doesn't do that, so you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagegenerators is not an attribute, it's a module inside pywikibot: https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/pagegenerators.py

Submodules are not imported automatically in this particular module, that's why you have to write `from pywikibot import pagegenerators`.

Comment: OK, and as said in the duplicate : "Submodules don't automatically get imported when you just `import X`".

Comment: ...and as I describe in my comment, it's not quite this simple in the general case.  But I see that @HeavenlyRaven may be talking about just this module specifically, in which case he is correct.